# Work internet redirecting to Twitch?

Tags: dns, dns-spoofing, browser-hijacking

When connecting my laptop with the work LAN, I noticed that certain websites get redirected always to a twitch channel. 
I have changed the DNS configuration and used 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, but the problem is persisting.

However, when I connect my laptop to another internet source and with the same DNS configuration, the problem disappears and I get redirected to the right website.

- What are the possible sources of the problem?
- Are the work LAN routers infected?
- Why is it happening only in some websites?

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of potential reasons for this. It could be a misconfigured DNS, the firewall, a work-installed agent on your machine. Or someone on the local network is maliciously redirecting traffic. A network tech might have configured the firewall to redirect certain sites to their favourite Twitch channel so that their browser history looks work-related, but doesn't realise that the entire network is affected.

There are a lot of potential reasons for internet traffic to go to unexpected places.

We cannot tell you the source of the problem from your description alone or why it is only happening on certain sites. Someone with networking knowledge would have to run a packet capture to start to run down the problem.

You need to be working with your IT team. They are the appropriate people to ask about this.